# Injected resource invalid: ManagedExecutorService

Tags: jakarta-ee, intellij-idea, wildfly

I have a JEE application running in a WildFly 10. One of the `@Stateless` beans has a dependency on

```
@Resource private ManagedExecutorService managedExecutorService;
```

It actually works! However, IntelliJ complains about it saying *‘Injected resource type '…' invalid’*. Is IntelliJ wrong here? If so, how do I suppress that error? Or is the injection incorrect and perhaps only works in WildFly?

Comment: Looks like there are related issues on YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-135465, https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-34395

Answer (score 1):

This is indeed a very long standing bug in IntelliJ, stemming from the fact that prior to JEE7 this was indeed not possible.
Seems they never got around to removing that flag.

Can suppress the warning easily enough with an IntelliJ specific @SuppressWarnings but if you do Sonar may complain (in our environment Sonar is set up to flag all @SuppressWarnings annotations as critical bugs).